# Create string with placeholder character

Tags: python

Is there a one liner in python that will give me the same result as below? All I need to supply is a int value and then it return a string using @.

results in a string with '@' appended for each loop.

```
padding = ''
for x in range(5): 
    padding += '@'
print padding
```

Results:

```
@@@@@
```

Comment: Will `"@" * 5` work?

Comment: never knew that was possible. Awesome thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, strings are sequence types, so the easiest way is:

```
print '@'*5
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is in the middle of some other formatting, you might use something like:

```
'{:@<{}}'.format('', 5)
```

(the inner `{}` expands to `5` before the outer formatting applies)

Comment: For that, `rjust` might also work: `"abc".rjust(5, "@") == '@@abc'`